# How to lookup data with a partial match on search key

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have two spreadsheets.  The first has a column with employee job IDs with commas seperating them (e.x: 123DB, 345CX, 031DB).  The second spreadsheet has the job IDs and the description.  For instance, 123D is Financial Advisor, 345C is Manager, etc... It is not an exact match because some of the other numbers and letters represent skill and other things.

So basically, I want to search the second spreadsheet for the job ID and print the description in a new column on that first spreadsheet (but it's not an exact match; like 123BD=123XB=123AP).  I'm not sure if VLOOKUP is what I want. Please and thank you!

Also, there are tens of thousands of rows to brute force isn't possible.  I plan to get more descriptive as I go on so if 23D is finance, 23D04 is a financial regulator or something.

[image: Desired Result]

Comment: Hi, @Alex. It sounds like VLOOKUP might be what you need. However, it is really hard to see what we are working with by just typing this description. 

You might consider using https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables to create a table structure you can paste right into your question to help us understand what exactly the spreadsheets look like, and where the data is. Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: I believe your example shows 43DB matching against 43BD. Is this a typo or Manager matching to just the 43 at the start? The Job ID in the lookup table needs to contain just the part that is common to all matching Employee Job IDs.

Comment: @Michael this was just a typo

Comment: Okay cool. We could still use a screenshot or something to understand the layout of the data better... your example so far looks like everything is on just the first row of each sheet.

Comment: @Michael. I added a screenshot. Hope it helps. Can't use the real data for privacy reasons, etc...

Comment: Yeah that helps a lot. Now we need to know: How many possible codes can be combined in a single cell? Formulas can't "loop over all values" in a cell; we instead need to nest multiple iterations of the lookup formula for each value that needs to be looked up. We only want to do this as many times as necessary. Twice isn't too bad, three or more starts to get pretty cumbersome.

Comment: Also, the screenshot shows "D23D13" as an ID #, which matches to "23D" Job Code. Until now, the Job Code had always been at the start of the ID #. Can they actually appear in the middle or is this another typo? This is important as it changes how we have to search for the codes.

Comment: @Michael Yes, it unfortunately the IDs can appear in the middle when it starts with a letter.  That's just the database I received and does make things more difficult.  Up to 18 can be combined into a single cell, but I can manually break it up with text-to-columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah you can't comfortably deal with that many IDs in a single formula. Below is the formula for finding the Description for a single ID # in cell A2.

This formula assumes the description lookup range has been converted to a table that has been named "Jobs".

Also, this is an array formula that needs to be entered using `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER`

`=INDEX(Jobs[Description],MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Jobs[Job Code],A2)),0))`

Considering it is searching for this in the middle of a string that seems to contain various other random numbers and letters, you may get some false matches. These are hard to avoid without there being a more fixed structure to the IDs.

Comment: I'll give this a try when I go into work on Monday. Thanks so much!

Comment: This worked for a lots of the cells. Thanks for your assistance.